Long click is consumed in the activity started for task, not on launcher activity
In Homescreen task view is used to show Navigation activity in the widget. When Homescreen is visible, the Navigation activity is started and becomes the top activity. Here the navigation activity is part of a third party application. When user touches the widget for long click, it is not consumed in the launcher fragment. When user perform long click on Navi widget, the click is consumed in the fragment created for task view.
How to switch the touch focus to the launcher activity when user touches on other widgets?
